# Generic mappings and associating values with keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following example (which is a simplification of more complicated code):

```
type NumMap = {
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 3,
}

type Proc<M extends { [key: string]: number }> = {
  go<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K];
};

const numMapProc: Proc<NumMap> = {
  go: key => {
    if (key === "one") return 1;
    if (key === "two") return 2;
    if (key === "three") return 3;

    throw new Error("whoops");
  }
}
```

When trying this out, I get the following error on the implementation of `go()`:

```
Type '<K extends "one" | "two" | "three">(key: K) => 1 | 2 | 3' is not assignable to type '<K extends "one" | "two" | "three">(key: K) => NumMap[K]'.
  Type '1 | 2 | 3' is not assignable to type 'NumMap[K]'.
    Type '1' is not assignable to type 'NumMap[K]'.
      Type '1' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Why does `NumMap[K]` get reduced to `never` here? Isn't `K` locked into extending `"one" | "two" | "three"`? Is there a value for `K` that satisfies the constraint but indexes `NumMap` and gives `never`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler sees the function

```
const f = <K extends keyof NumMap>(key: K) => {
  if (key === "one") return 1;
  if (key === "two") return 2;
  if (key === "three") return 3;
  throw new Error("whoops");
}
```

and can only verify that its return type is `1 | 2 | 3`, not `NumMap[K]`.  In general the compiler does not use control flow analysis to narrow type parameters like `K`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).  So in the case that `key === "one"`, you could possibly expect the type of `key` to be narrowed from `K` to `"one"` or `K & "one"` or something, but the type `K extends keyof NumMap` itself remains stubbornly the same and does not get narrowed to something like `K extends "one"`.  And so, the compiler is unhappy when you use that in place of something that accepts `NumMap[K]`.

The particular *`never`* error is due to a change implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) to be more careful when trying to assign values *to* a variable of an indexed type like `NumMap[K]`.  If `K` is or can be a union like `"one" | "two" | "three"`, then the compiler will only allow an assignment if the value is an *intersection* of the properties at those keys, or basically `NumMap["one"] & NumMap["two"] & NumMap["three"]`, which is `1 & 2 & 3`, which gets collapsed to `never` (because no value can be `1` and `2` and `3` at the same time).  All this means is that the compiler is worried that you are getting a `1` or a `2` or a `3` and it might not always be the right one.

---

So, how do we fix this?  The easiest thing is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing.  This is tedious but at least a *little bit* safe in that it will at least complain if you return something completely off-the-map like `4` or `true`:

```
const numMapProcAsserts: Proc<NumMap> = {
  go: <K extends keyof NumMap>(key: K) => {
    if (key === "one") return 1 as NumMap[K];
    if (key === "two") return 2 as NumMap[K];
    if (key === "three") return 3 as NumMap[K];
    throw new Error("whoops");
  }
}
```

Or you can use a single `any` assertion to just silence the compiler: claim that the function returns `any` and both the implementation and the assignment will be happy, but don't expect the compiler to help you if you change `return 3;` to `return "oopsie";`:

```
const numMapProcOneAssert: Proc<NumMap> = {
  go: (key): any => {
    if (key === "one") return 1;
    if (key === "two") return 2;
    if (key === "three") return 3;

    throw new Error("whoops");
  }
}
```

Another idea would be to refactor your function so that the compiler can actually follow the logic of what you're doing.  If the return type is supposed to be a lookup/indexed access type, you can perform an actual indexed access of the right type and the compiler will be happy.  In your case, if you want a `NumMap[K]`, show the compiler that you're indexing into an object of type `NumMap` with a key of type `K`:

```
const numMapProcIdx: Proc<NumMap> = {
  go: <K extends keyof NumMap>(key: K) =>
    (({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 } as const)[key])
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwLIEMxQLxQN4FgBQUUARAPYB2ExAXFAIwA0BRxwA7qTVAExOEnAAFgCcIVWgGY+AXwIFQkKAAVhpAMYAeJFAgAPYBHIATAM44oAbQDWEELRPBhAS3IBzALq1yiAEYRhUNIAfJg4zFCupBoA0jr6hqZQNiCkAGZQSEEAFMm00QCUtEgW0e4A3ATSFfgEahQOUN7IaCrqtK2a8M1gIVh4-JG0Obb5mCH9RERO6cMgmBhYZJTEo6LAcMLk9NWTUNNQs-OL7JyrEOubPDuT+4cLxyJiK1BrG1sS1eFEQqpsjRB-ACiwlUwiyxDYglIpDAJhW11k+ERtXqwCg6SwMTiBmMZmSaVgiFQPVmeVGGHG4VuySOJAoVDOFy2dGu1NstNYHGer0u3FZMxp9wEjwZL3ObygH3CP1If0oQJBpDBEKhMLh+WqyPwdXIDSaxI6AEETCZ-MATO1VJ0iWhemEBqRaFi9DjEvj0l1idlclACmN7bs2XMhUtRTzmVAUGZPWgSuUvnsBeyQydueLeZHozawHHrlMk8GFsLRGH0+9M4TurmEzK5QCoMDQeDIdDYfDwoitTq9dmOgB5SjG03CYCW9QaGM9UITCKOg7JQqR8jByn8fPz5NF0NppnbBNBjmpxkSvn7guHkU7iVSmprqC1-4Kpsq1vqhGVOS37to-UtK0ASSMXQx2tbo7RnQYoGdeJcSSWwCUnb1bDJMYEyyLJsCgelaEYe8OFoXh7xFSRAgrb98msWx3HyD9b0-IA)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer with links to relevant GH issues. I’m not super happy with the decisions TS is making that leads to issue #13995, but at least now I understand what’s going on. 

Unfortunately, the actual version of the code makes establishing a map more difficult (or, at least, way more tedious). Casting is a good escape hatch though, especially like that internal `any` trick.